# Python AddIns Installation Tool Not Showing After Double Clicking on makeaddin.py

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, python-addin

I am using Python Add-In Wizard with ArcGIS 10.4.1 but after getting the files I am not able to create installation Wizard!

[image]

I tried to create the wizard by double clicking on the [image]  looks like something running but No installation file generated at the directory! can you please let me know why this is happening?

> Update

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class ButtonClass3(object):
    """Implementation for ESRI Addin Python_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        pass

class ComboBoxClass1(object):
    """Implementation for ESRI Addin Python_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = ["item1", "item2"]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        pass
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        pass
    def refresh(self):
        pass

class ComboBoxClass2(object):
    """Implementation for ESRI Addin Python_addin.combobox_1 (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = ["item1", "item2"]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        pass
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        pass
    def refresh(self):
        pass
```

Comment: hmm. what does the python script inside your Install folder look like?

Comment: Please take a look at update Carolyn

Comment: Well, that looks right to me, though I'm usually just using a def onClick(self) in mine... There might be some issue with the python version you're using - have you checked this answer yet? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155012/making-python-add-ins-for-arcmap-after-installing-arcgis-pro-prevents-double-cli

Comment: well, here is what I got `2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]` by running the `print (sys.version)`

Comment: Run it from the command prompt (or your IDE or whatever) instead of double-clicking it.  That way the window will stay open and you can see any errors

Comment: The answer of bperham works for me with ArcGIS 10.6.1 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem with the makeaddin.py file recently and it turned out to be a bug in the file.  Make sure the print command near the bottom of the file has parenthesis around "archive file", so Print (archive_file). Doing this fixed my problem.

[image]

Comment: `print` is a statement in Python 2x, you don't need parentheses.  Parentheses are only required in Python 3 (as `print()` is a function) but Python 3 is only supported in ArcGIS Pro which does not support [Python Add Ins](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/what-is-a-python-add-in.htm).