# Select IDLE 2.7 (not 3.4) as default script tool editor for ArcPy with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, installation, idle

I'm trying to set my default editor in ArcMap (10.3) to IDLE 2.7, but despite using the 2.7 path, when I right-click on a script tool and select Edit, it opens IDLE 3.4:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: right click > edit from within Arc* or in Windows Explorer?

Comment: @KHibma - correct. I'm right-clicking on a script tool and selecting Edit. But then instead of IDLE 2.7 opening, IDLE 3.4 is opening, despite setting the "Script Tool Editor" path to 2.7."

Comment: You're probably running into [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140923/distinguishing-python-version-when-using-idle-with-arcgis-pro-and-arcgis-10-x-fo). Though its weird the specific idle.pyw you're pointing at has been hijacked to use 3.4.

Comment: @KHibma That's definitely what's going on. I actually read that answer a while back and added both "Edit with IDLE 2.7" and "Edit with IDLE 3.4" to my right-click context menu by editing my registry. It's been a great workaround for editing scripts just in folders. But I can't seem to find a similar workaround for right-clicking on a script in a toolbox to edit it in IDLE 2.7. And when I try to set the default editor to PythonWIN or even Notepad++ then just nothing happens. So frustrating.

Comment: I think it could be worth retesting this on a machine with ArcGIS 10.4.1 for Desktop and ArcGIS Pro 1.3 (installed in that order) because http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/installing-python-for-arcgis-pro.htm suggests the ArcPy install from Pro is done differently now.  I have that combination on my laptop but do not have it with me to test.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on a machine with ArcGIS 10.4.1 for Desktop and ArcGIS Pro 1.3 (installed in that order) because http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/installing-python-for-arcgis-pro.htm suggests the ArcPy install from Pro is done differently now.

The IDLE editor now opens predictably from ArcGIS for Desktop with Python 2.7.4.

Comment: Fantastic! We are getting new machines at work and will have 10.4 as well. Once we get them I will test it out and report back.