# Editing validation code for Python script tool in ArcGIS Pro using IDLE?

Tags: python-script-tool, arcgis-pro, tool-validation, idle

I created and successfully tested a Python script tool, for which I included some validation code, in ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1.

To write the validation code I right-clicked on the Python script tool in its standard toolbox to open its Tool Properties, went to the Validation tab and clicked <kbd>Open in Script Editor</kbd>.

This opened IDLE, allowed me to edit the code, and after I saved and closed IDLE, clicked OK to close the Tool Properties, and ran the tool the validation that I had just set clearly worked.

Five minutes later I went to enhance the validation code using the same editing workflow but found that clicking <kbd>Open in Script Editor</kbd> no longer opened IDLE to allow me to edit it.

I have rebooted my machine and the <kbd>Open in Script Editor</kbd> button is still no longer opening IDLE.

Via comments at the time I determined that I could get a very suboptimal script editor in Notepad to work by using the Ribbon to access ANALYSIS | Geoprocessing Options to set the Script Editor to `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`.

However, doing the same thing to try and set the Script Editor to `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\idlelib\i‌​‌​dle.pyw` returns the <kbd>Open in Script Editor</kbd> button to doing nothing.

---

I few weeks later I moved to another machine which had been upgraded to ArcGIS Pro 1.4.1 and I was hoping that would fix whatever was astray but it has not.

**Is there any other method that can be used to be able to always edit the validation code for a Python script tool of ArcGIS Pro by using a Python IDE better than Notepad?**

---

I have considered re-writing the tool as a Python Toolbox (`*.pyt`)but the site I am working with are more comfortable using Standard Toolboxes (`*.tbx`) so I would like to avoid doing that.

Comment: That's a really good question... is the button greyed out or does nothing happen when you click it? I assume that editing a script tool still opens IDLE so the external program is not the issue, should this be the case it might have to raised with Esri support. Can you edit/create the validator for tools that don't currently have one or is unmodified? Can you copy the script tool to a fresh toolbox and try there... perhaps the toolbox went a little funny or is from an older version and no longer truly compatible.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson It's not greyed out, it just spins for a split second then stops.  Right-clicking on scripts and choosing `Edit with IDLE (ArcGIS Pro)` still works fine.  Creating a new Python script tool does not let me set tool validation for it either so it seems like IDLE is working but tool validation is failing to use it to edit the tool validation code in a scratch file like it would normally.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Copying the tool to a new toolbox does not let me edit its validation code there either.

Comment: Perhaps set a different editor like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188913/select-idle-2-7-not-3-4-as-default-script-tool-editor-for-arcpy-with-arcgis-fo to refresh the registry setting - I know it's for desktop but perhaps there's a similar setting in Pro... Notepad would probably do for a test but PyWin or even Notepad++ are better editors than Notepad in the long run. It could also have to do with your temp folder, the script would need to be extracted to edit then encoded back to the toolbox when saved, there could be something wrong with that process.

Comment: In desktop the validator is extracted to %tmp% for editing, the %tmp% you would get from ArcCatalog python window by typing print os.environ.get('tmp') as ArcGis creates a fresh temp for each instance inside the system temp directory called arcXXXX where XXXX is a random 4 digit hex. Whist editing the main thread is suspended and the validator is encoded back to the toolbox when the editor is closed.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Setting the Script Editor (which was blank) in the Geoprocessing Options to `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe` does enable it to be open in Notepad.  I suspect that when I can figure ArcGIS Pro's hiding place for the IDLE I am using I may be on my way.

Comment: C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw for desktop 10.2.. it's not an exe for idle but a python tool.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I tried `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\python\envs\arcgispro-py3\pythonw.exe` for ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1 and now it spins for a few seconds before not opening IDLE.

Comment: That's the interpreter, you need to call the pyw file from the Lib directory, shellexecute should handle Pythonw.exe for you - if not no scripts would run in a command window. Don't forget if there's a space in the path you need to quote it.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I just tried `"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\idlelib\idle.pyw"` with and without quotes (single and double) and its gone back to spinning for only a split second.

Comment: And that's the correct path on your system for idle... does the IDLE editor open if you double click on it in explorer? Are your python scripts still working still by double click in explorer or on command line?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Python scripts still open in IDLE if I right-click and choose `Edit with IDLE (ArcGIS Pro)`. If I double-click `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\idlelib\i‌​dle.pyw` it opens Python shell window but for 2.7.10 instead of expected 3.4.4.  I never run my Python scripts by double-clicking them or from the command line.

Comment: The correct version must be somewhere else... Try a search for IDLE on your system drive and you should be able to find the correct one. The double click test is to ensure that shellexecute for type *.py is still set to pythonw.exe, if it doesn't work then you need to set your 'opens with' in explorer for the file type to the interpreter.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I'm going to have to bail on trying to do more with this because I am on a machine that I am handing back to its owner.  At the moment I know that I have not changed any system settings so I can do that with a clear conscience.  I'll resume looking at this on Tuesday when I have a different machine using ArcGIS Pro 1.4.1 instead.  Many thanks for all your help this afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this situation, which I have not been able to resolve, is to re-write the tool so that it resides in a Python Toolbox rather than being a Python script tool in a standard toolbox.

Upgrading a second machine to ArcGIS Pro 1.4.1 shows the same problem so I am beginning to think that whatever the issue is may be related to how this enterprise performs their installs.

I know that it is not a permissions problem with the `*.tbx` that I am trying to edit because setting the Script Editor to `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe` enables it to be edited but in a very sub-optimal way.  This dialog is reached from ANALYSIS | Geoprocessing and clicking the small arrow at its bottom right.

[image]

---

My current workaround is to:

1. Set the Script Editor to C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe to enable an editor to be opened
2. Open a New File in IDLE to use as a scratch pad
3. Open the tool Properties to its Validation tab and copy/paste the nicely formatted code from there into the IDLE window
4. Edit in IDLE and when happy with the changes Copy them into the paste buffer
5. Click <kbd>Open in Script Editor</kbd> to open Notepad with the poorly formatted code
6. In Notepad Ctrl-A (to select all) and Ctrl-V (to paste the contents of the paste buffer and replace what was there)
7. Save the code in Notepad, and then close Notepad
8. Click OK to accept the changes to the tool validation
9. Test the tool to see that its tool validation code has been changed